# How to load react native JS bundle from network in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

For my Android app, I need to be able to dynamically update the Bundle at runtime and use the pre-saved bundle in my Assets as a fall back. I have failed to find any information on this in the [Official Documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content)

In the iOS version of react native, there is a method that lets you specify a URL from which to load the JS bundle, but I have yet to see an equivalent option for Android. How is this possible for Android?

**Update**
It looks like the RN team has been working on this very feature and will be part of the next release:
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3a743ef228a14e07c77c5488b080413643ec9c4b

Answer (score 6):

1.download bundle file(s) and manage the path(s).

2.new a ReactNativeHost in your Application:

```
public String mBundleFilePath = "";
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.asList(new MainReactPackage(), new MyReactPackage());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
        return mBundleFilePath;
    }
};
```

3.before starting a ReactActivity, assign the path of ur bundle file to variable: mBundleFilePath.

```
public class ReactNativeActivity extends ReactActivity {
    public static void launchSelf(...) {
        MyApplication.getInstance().mBundleFilePath = path;
        COMPONENT_NAME = ...;
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity,ReactNativeActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(..);
    }
    ...
}
```

source code:

```
com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost#createReactInstanceManager
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.Builder#setJSBundleFile
com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JSBundleLoader#createFileLoader
```

...

may it help u : )

Comment: Am able to download and set the bundle but none of the images are displayed and same is working fine If I set the bundle from asset folder

Comment: I am facing the same issue images are not loaded i knwe this is old question but any hint on how to make the images show is highly appreciated.My RN version is 0.51

Comment: probably because you should use your own image loader or use external images (i.e. from the cloud).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. you can give [Code Push](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/tree/first-check-in-for-android) a try(but their android version not stable yet), or find out how to do that in their code.

Comment: Code push is very good tool for dynamicaly loading js and publish updates to it