# Require locally packaged assets in remotely downloaded js bundle

Tags: react-native

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40257239/2805519) to download js bundle each time my app starts because I want an easy way to deploy minor changes during development stage.

The downloaded file is the one I exract from built apk. However, no images required in js (like `require('../grapic/pic.png')`) show up when application is run in this mode.

I save the js file like this:

```
File jsCodeDir = getApplicationContext().getDir("assets", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File f = new File(jsCodeDir, "remote.android.jsbundle");
// ... download file and put it into f
```

It seems that the problem is with paths: js isn't able to require images when it is stored in `assets/` folder of internal storage, as opposed to when it is run from default `assets/` folder from within apk.

So the question: is there a way to make a bundle such that it is able to use locally packaged resources (images from within apk just like locally packaged js does).