# How to load react native JS bundle from network in Android full proof example?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I looking into this [How to load react native JS bundle from network in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511835/how-to-load-react-native-js-bundle-from-network-in-android) solution. 
I am not able load js bundle using above example.

Can someone please give me full example so that I get complete view of the same.

Thank you in Advance !

Comment: Do you need to load it from the network every time the app starts or you want to push bundle updates to your app?

Comment: @HunaidHassan 
I need to load it from network at first time and cache it till new changes. after it automatically download new changes and again cache it.

Comment: @HunaidHassan, I need to load it from network at first time and cache it. I will check bundle updates for every app start,if bundle modified i will download the same and again cache it.

Comment: @HunaidHassan You can also tell me, how to load the jsbundle from remote every time on every app starts.

Comment: I see. In that case, you should look at the pre-made solutions e.g. Expo's OTA or Microsoft's Code Push. They do exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: @HunaidHassan Thank you !